# Failed to pass variable from one sub routine to another sub routine using perl cgi?

Tags: perl, cgi

---

Here i had tried to pass variable from one sub routine to another sub routine using perl cgi.But my variable is not passing from one sub routine to another,

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI ':standard';
print header;
print start_html("example");
print end_html;
my $file = "text.txt";
open my $fh,'<', $file or die $!;
sub1($fh);
sub2($fh);

sub sub1 {
   my $fh = shift;
   while ( my $line = <$fh> ) {
      print $line;
   }
   return $fh;
}

sub sub2 {
   my $line = shift;
   print start_form;
   print "<table>";
   print "<th>content</th>";
   print "<tr>";
   print "<td>$line<td>";
   print "</tr>";
   print "</table>";
   print end_form;
}
```

In the above sub routine (i.e sub2 $line contents are not passing from sub1)

Comment: You pass the file handle  ($fh) not a "normal" variable ($line)

Comment: That code you've given us doesn't compile. Show us your _actual_ code. But Jens is probably right - you call `sub2($fh)` and then try and use `$fh` as if it were a line.

Comment: i had already called sub2($fh) at first itself@Sobrique

Comment: Which variable do you want to pass from one subroutine to another? Your code doesn't do that at all. You pass the same variable (`$fh`) to two different subroutines. But your `sub2()` looks like you meant to pass it a line from the file rather than the filehandle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you wanted

```
my $content = sub1($fh);
sub2($content);

sub sub1 {
    my $fh = shift;
    my $content;
    while ( my $line = <$fh> ) {
        print $line;
        $content .= $line;
    }
    return $content;
}
```

Also file handle $fh can be close after sub1 call

Comment: in secoond subroutine should i need to use shift as like my $fh=shift.@Nahuel Fouilleul

Comment: to read arguments you can use `shift(@_)` or `my ($x,$y,@etc)=@_;` idioms ; so in this case : `my ($content)=@_;` , or also `$content=$_[0];` ; in perl there's always "more than one way to do it"